# Percorrendo array de Objetos e acessando um valor

Tags: php, json, array, foreach, objetos

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade, aonde preciso acessar um elemento de um array de OBJETOS, não estou conseguindo acessar com o foreach, ou for. Preciso da ajuda de vocês!

O array de objetos:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pk] => 1343200701115549070
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pk] => 1339248324134135231
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pk] => 1338844272896371640
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pk] => 1338841774089501872
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pk] => 1338838365890273563
        )
```

Eu preciso pegar as os valores da "pk" para colocando em uma outra variável.
Para complementar a explicação, esse array é um arquivo em json_encode, aonde eu abro arquivo e transformo em json_decode:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($caminho);
        while (!$file->eof()) {
           $id_line1 = $file->fgets();
        }
        $id_line = json_decode($id_line1);
```

Vlw abraço!!

Comment: Faça um foreach e chama assim a propriedade `$item->pk`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com essa iteração você pega o conteúdo da key:

```
foreach ($array_de_objetos as $key => $value){
    echo $value->pk;
}
```

Comment: Nossa, cara eu tentei de tudo, menos isso kkkk. Ajudou muito valeu, grande abraço!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Foreach creates a copy

$array = [
  "foo" => ['bar', 'baz'],
  "bar" => ['foo'],
  "baz" => ['bar'],
  "batz" => ['end']
];

// while(list($i, $value) = each($array)) { // Try this next
foreach($array as $i => $value) {
  print $i . "\n";
  foreach($value as $index) {
    unset($array[$index]);
  }
}

print_r($array); // array('baz' => ['end'])
```

Você tem um objeto interpretado dentro de uma lista, fazendo o acesso ficar mais complicado, tenha certeza que você entende como acessar essa variável por fora do array, e faça o mesmo dentro do array. Esse exemplo aqui mosta array dentro de array e coo executar corretamente o laço.

Answer (score 0):

Estou vendo um código aonde a variável de interação seria `$id_line`:

```
    $file = new SplFileObject($caminho);
    while (!$file->eof()) 
    {
        $id_line1 = $file->fgets();
    }
    $id_line = json_decode($id_line1);

   foreach($id_line as $line)
   {
     $textoPK = $line->pk;
   }
```